# How to write a string to standard output from Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rhino, java-8, nashorn

I am interested in a portable way of writing a string to standard output, without implicit newlines added to the end, ideally forcing encoding to UTF-8, that works with either of

- jrunscript (from any JDK)
- Rhino
- node.js

My current code tries to detect where it is running, then uses a platform-specific write method:

```
  if (typeof process !== "undefined") {     // assume node.js
    var log = function(string) {process.stdout.write(string);};
  }
  else if (typeof println == "undefined") { // assume rhino
    var log = function(string) {java.lang.System.out.write(java.lang.String(string).getBytes("utf-8"));};
  }
  else {                                    // assume jrunscript
    var log = function(string) {java.lang.System.out.print(string);};
  }
  log("X");
  log("Y");
```

It should result in:

```
  XY
```

Can this be done better?

For jrunscript, I had been using function `print`, but that changed its behavior in JDK-8 on behalf of [JDK-8021773](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021773).

Comment: I think you will *need* platform-specific code

Comment: I have similar code in my project. Note that you'll want to test on Nashorn too. (Java 8 bundles Nashorn, not Rhino.)

Comment: @SethTisue, thanks for the hint. In fact upgrading JDK to 8 was what got me thinking about this again. Also, Rhino and its (pre-8) JDK flavor already needed to be distinguished to this respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am interested in a portable way of writing a 
>   string to standard output, without implicit newlines added to the end, ideally forcing
>   encoding to UTF-8, that works with either of...

there is none,since javascript doesnt have "system apis". JS core is limited and you need to use the api available within the environment javascript engine is running in.

> My current code tries to detect where it is running, then uses a
>   platform-specific write method. But I'd rather get rid of that.

that's the only thing you can do.

EDIT : the javascript spec is here : http://es5.github.io/ and it's short,there is 0 notion of standard output or standard input because there is no javascript standard library.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I'll keep my platform distinction code, as shown in the question.